# CSS Animation isn't working. Flashing quickly then ending

Tags: css, animation

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tv3k2dwL/

My CSS:

```css
#returned_data{
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  animation-name: border-animation;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@keyframes border-animation {
  0%{
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
  25%{
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
  50%{
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, green, blue);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
  75%{
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, blueviolet);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
  100%{
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, blueviolet, steelblue);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
}
```

This is a short gif of what's going on right now:

https://i.gyazo.com/ea8920f97a6539e5779f75a0f7583339.gif (Can't post images because I'm under 10 rep)

I'm not really sure why that happens. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: can you post html or jsfiddle

Comment: I added a jsfiddle uptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current `animation-timing-function` you're using is causing the issue, try using
`animation-timing-function: step-start;`
This behavior seems to be isolated to how chrome is handling `ease-in-out`

```
#returned_data{
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  animation-name: border-animation;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: step-start;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

See it in action [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpsh/gn8rsvyh/3/)

Also on a side note, I see you're using `$.post` but you're not posting any data, I recommend using `$.get`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you man. Wouldn't have known about the chrome issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the transition property and give some 2 seconds.

Comment: I added the transition-duration: 1s, didn't work :(